# Read in file in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using blazor webassembly and I want my model to read a .tsv or .csv file from my sample-data folder. I know that I can use

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        fileName = await Http.GetStringAsync("sample-data/randomFile.tsv");
    }
```

but then it spits out as a string and I can't use my file reader functions like .ReadAllLines(). How do I get access to the file just as it is?

EDIT:
I realize that I can pass it as a string and parse the string. The problem now is that the string doesn't make it to the model.

```
@code {
    static string fileName = "this \n is \n a \n test";
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        fileName = await Http.GetStringAsync("sample-data/22_AB9_CL_0228.tsv");
    }
    string[,] table = FileReader.ConvertToMatrix(fileName, "sample-data/randomFile.tsv");
}
```

The model receives "this \n is \n a \n test"

Comment: A remote file accessed via HTTP is not a file in the sense you mean it, in terms of `System.IO.File`.  That said, methods like `.ReadAllLines` are hardly difficult to replicate.  Just split on new lines.

Comment: Problem is that when I pass it as an argument from a component to a model class, it isn't readable inside the model.

Comment: The first part is answered by `Http.GetStreamAsync(....)`. The Edit part is hard to follow but unlikely to work.

Comment: I want to be able to pass what Http.GetStreamAsync(....) gives me to a class. But it doesn't seem to leave the scope of protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()

Comment: Step 1 is to get the data access stuff out of the UI and into a service.  Inject and call the service from the component.  In the service you can do all the normal C# stream stuff once you use `Http.GetStreamAsync(....)` to get the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You have the StringReader class in System.IO that can parse string using CR or CRLF line separator.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://filesamples.com/samples/document/csv/sample2.csv");
string fileContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // This method looks at content-type header to find how string is encoded (UTF8, ASCII, ...)
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(fileContent))
{
    string? line = null;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine())!=null)
    {
        string[] items = line.Split(",");
        // Process the items
    }
}
```